# If statement doesn't work with downloaded data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

I've written some code that posts data to a MySql database via PHP and the PHP code returns a value of either 'YES' or 'NO' via JSON. I then have an if statement that checks whether it is YES or NO. The if statement works perfectly when I set the 'worked' string manually, but not if I use the data from JSON. I have checked that it is set correctly using NSLog, and I really can't see what the problem could be. Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
-(void) dataDownloaded {
    NSDictionary *theDictionary = [_theArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *worked = [theDictionary objectForKey:@"worked"];

    NSLog(@"%@", worked);

    if (worked == @"NO") {
        //code for if it didn't work
    } else if (worked == @"YES"){
        //code for if it did work
    } else {
        //code for if it doesn't return either value
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can work out what the problem is!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're using `==` to compare. That's not going to work. I think you need to read up on Objective-C - try http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/ for that. Here's how you should fix your code:

```
-(void) dataDownloaded {
    NSDictionary *theDictionary = [_theArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *worked = [theDictionary objectForKey:@"worked"];

    NSLog(@"%@", worked);

    if ([worked isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
        //code for if it didn't work
    } else if ([worked isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
        //code for if it did work
    } else {
        //code for if it doesn't return either value
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a really stupid mistake! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

use isEqualToString: for string comparsions

```
if ([worked isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {

}
```